# Oracle Apex: Place buttons within html table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

One thing about Oracle Apex that I just don't get is the lack of freedom when it comes to styling and placing things on a page. I have three Oracle Apex "buttons" that I would like to place inside a html table that has a table headers on it. Because Oracle Apex requires me to create an Apex Button object it places it on the page for me within a region. Is there a way that I can tell Apex that I would like to place those buttons within a table? Not an oracle apex report just a plain old html table. Sorry this might be such a basic question but I can't seem to find any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. You can use the [APEX_ITEM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#CACEEEJE) package to create all sorts of form elements and place them wherever you want, but not buttons. I think you can create just a regular HTML button and add some Javascript that loads the correct URL when pressed. Most page items and such you can set in the URL.

Comment: Agreed that you cant create buttons with APEX_ITEM but you can create the html tag manually yourself and if its in the FORM tag it will submit the page without any problem. You just have to know how to create that tag and what it needs to have in order for it to be seen as valid by wwv_flow.accept : it need to have mandatory the name parameter f01..f50  i.e. <input type="button" onclick="doSubmit('SAVE_REQUEST')" value="Go!" tabindex="3" id="btn_currency" name="f46"> => this is a valid apex button that will submit the page with the request as : SAVE_REQUEST.

Comment: That's very true. That's just not really an "Apex button", where you can control and define it through the Apex interface. That's really just an HTML object that you're putting on the page. But, you're right, that does work.

Comment: I have simple submit button with html region but it shows BAD REQUEST after submit

Comment: I would suggest creating a new question about this rather than posting as a comment to a four year old answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is a Custom Region. Version 4 also has a style free DIV in the same vein as this (no markup, just a DIV) and Parent/Child relationship for regions now too.

Answer (score 0):

Apex is as flexible as you want it to be.

To submit a form you can :add your hand written code  `<input type="submit" value="mybutton" />` or you can do it from practically any html tag that is clickable.

Try to add this where you would like the page to be submitted from :

```
<div>
  <a href="javascript:doSubmit('SAVE')" style="display:block;border:1px solid red;padding:3px;">SAVE</a>
</div>
```

Note that what is passed to the **doSubmit()** function is the **:REQUEST** that you can handle in your PL/SQL.